# Trim a cell with VBA in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the trim function without success. After searching for the solution on this forum and other sources online I have seen many different approaches.

Is there no simple way of trimming a cell in VBA?

What I want is something like this:

```
Sub trimloop()

Dim row As Integer

row = 1

Do While Cells(row, 1) <> ""

   Cells(row, 2) = trim(Cells(row, 2))

   row = row + 1

Loop
```

So that when there is a value in column A (1) the value in column B (2) should be trimmed of any extra spaces. I just cant get this to work for me.

Appreciate any help/tips!

Regards
Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i made the code a bit accurate and mistakeproof and it worked.

So i can recommend you to double check, if you have correct row and column values, because you probably targeting wrong cells. (cause your code is working)

```
Sub trimloop()

Dim row As Integer
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Set currentSheet = sheets("Sheet1")

row = 2

Do While currentSheet.Cells(row, 1) <> ""

   currentSheet.Cells(row, 2).Value = Trim(currentSheet.Cells(row, 2).Value)

   row = row + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed targeting the wrong cell.. facepalm. Why do you do the Set currentSheet part and use current sheet? Is it not by default the current active sheet the code will run on?

Comment: I just do it this way :) i saw many mistakes in code caused by nonexact reference, and targeting the wrong sheets, that i rather do it everytime. Also when i look on cody after some time, i still know what i wana to do.

Comment: Without fully referencing the worksheet, when you say `Cells(row,1)`, you refer to the active sheet of whichever workbook is currently active. By fully qualifying the reference (which, personally, I would do as `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`), you ensure Excel doesn't try to "guess" which sheet you mean. Hope this helps!

Comment: Good point from @asongtoruin, but i personaly dont like using of multiple sheets at once, because some events are shared, and can do a big mess.... Atleast in my scenario worksheet_change, and etc

Comment: @Luboš Suk I assume you mean having multiple workbooks open at the same time - maybe you don't think it's ideal but if you're writing code that could be used by someone else you have to be aware of how they might choose to do things, which could include having multiple workbooks open!

Comment: @asongtoruin yes, you are absolutely correct. But in all cases im giving recomendation to use one workbook per time. Cause i meet realy ugly issues with multiple open workbooks and worksheet events :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(string)`

```
Sub trimloop()

Dim row As Integer

row = 1

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Do While .Cells(row, 1) <> ""

   .Cells(row, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Cells(row, 2))

   row = row + 1

Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did notice as Lubos pointed out that it was a simple mistake in the targeting of the cells. Can I ask why you would use ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet? What difference does it make?

Answer (score 1):

this is the optimized version of your code, in case of big data sheets:

```
Option Explicit

Sub trimloop()

Dim row As Long, max As Long
Dim Data() As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    max = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row 'this does the same as your code, on first empty cell it stops
    'the following finds the last un-empty cell of column(1):
    'max= .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row

    'copies values from sheet to memory (is faster for working with later)
    Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(max, 2)).Value2

    'loop :
    For row = 2 To max + 1

        'work with memory instead of sheet
        Data(row, 2) = Trim(Data(row, 2))
        'for complete delete of all spaces use : = replace( StringName," ", "")

    Next row

    'write back to sheet
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(max, 2)).Value2 = Data

End With

erase Data 'free memory

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this overly simplified... but thought I would simply throw it out there this worked for me. The only predecessor step is you assign a "named range" to your workbook/worksheet/dataset ... name a data set and then iterate over the data set with this code

```
Sub forEachLoop()
    For Each cell In Range("yourNamedRange")
        cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
    Next cell
End Sub
```